# Parsing itemprop properties with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, attributes

There is a website resembling this structure:

```
<div class="responsive1">
    <img class="maxed responsive-img" itemprop="contentUrl" alt="oneThing"   src="somethingElse">
</div>
```

...and when you look at its properties it is listed as:

```
img.maxed.responsive-img
    accessKey:""
    align:""
    alt:"something"
    assignedSlot:null
    childElementCount:0
    currentSrc:"http://www.webAddress.com"
```

So how do I specifically retrieve and change the currentSrc?
I can retrieve the itemProp property as a single element with this:

```
var elements = document.getElementsByTagName('img');
for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    var element = elements[i];
    var replacement = "somethingToReplaceCurrentSrc"
    var target = $('img[itemprop="contentUrl"]');
    for (var t = 0; t < latitude.length; t++ ) {
        console.log(t);
    }
```

How do I specify currentSrc and replace it with the variable target?

Comment: Ah, figured it out. The 'srcset' was re-updating everything, I thought the src attribute was being updated as an itemprop property/attribute....

Answer (score 0):

You should change your src, and the currentSrc should be updated (you shouldn't work with currentSrc)

```
$('img[itemprop="contentUrl"]').attr("src", replacement);
```

If you do this, the currentSrc will be updated.

Comment: I have already replaced the src, and this does not alter the currentSrc, hence the question. I added this line and it does not change that fact.
Thanks though.